# Symfony autowiring error 'Cannot autowire argument'

Tags: php, symfony, autowired

I want to use an Interface for the autowiring with Symfony. For that, I look up this [autowiring](https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/autowiring.html#working-with-interfaces) description. But I always get this Error:

> Cannot autowire argument $productStock of "App\Controller\WelcomeContoller::setDayText()": it references interface "src\Interfaces\ProductStockInterface" but no such service exists. Did you create a class that implements this interface?

I followed the description I link above and the code looks like this:

```
<?php
namespace src\Interfaces;

use src\Interfaces\Objects\HeaderObject;

interface ProductStockInterface
{
   public function getProductsMostBuyd():array;
   public function getSerchedProducts(string $productName):array;
   public function getHederSearchBar():HeaderObject;
   public function getProductsInSalle():array;
}
```

this is the Interface I want to use for the autowiring. This is the Class I using the Interface:

```
<?php
namespace src\Service;

use App\Repository\ProductRepository;
use src\Interfaces\ProductStockInterface;
use src\Interfaces\Objects\HeaderObject;

class ProductStockService implements ProductStockInterface
{
  private $productrepo;

  public function __construct(ProductRepository $productrepo){
      $this->productrepo = $productrepo;
  }

  public function getSerchedProducts($productName):array
  {
    return $this->productrepo->getMostBuydProducts(10);
  }

  public function getProductsMostBuyd():array
  {
    return $this->productrepo->getMostBuydProducts(10);
  }

  public function getHederSearchBar():HeaderObject
  {
    return new HeaderObject(['shoki'], ['https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schokolade']);   
  }

  public function getProductsInSalle():array
  {
    return $this->productrepo->getMostBuydProducts(10);
  }
}
```

like in the description I put this in the service.yaml:

```
services:

   App\Service\ProductStockService: ~
   App\Interfaces\ProductStockInterface: '@App\Service\ProductStockService'
```

I hope someone can help me with that.

thanks

Comment: I'm guessing you did not intend to use `src` as a PHP namespace prefix.  If you did for some odd reason then your services.yaml entries need to match.  However in this particular case I don't think you need any entries in services.yaml at all once your namespaces are sorted.  And `bin/console debug:container` can help quite a bit.